# Handling Dependency Injection & Arbitrary Simple Classes

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection

I'm in the process of refactoring a medium-scale MVC framework to use dependency injection, moving away from a mix of a service locator class + various other techniques, and towards a more consistent service provider/service container model similar to Laravel. Generally it's going well.

One of the things I'm slowly phasing out and trying to avoid is having a dependency on the service container itself. This is going OK as I move towards factories for certain types of classes and this seems to make good sense when it comes to the more important structural bones like controllers and repositories etc. However, one thing that I'm struggling to get my head around is how to do this for simple classes that you may either need to load various instances of, just need the odd one here or there or have in-place construction needs. For example I might want to instantiate a REST client a couple of times, or some kind of String handling utility where you pass it into the constructor, but also I might want to do this on only 1 out of 15 repositories, which already have their own factory class.

- Creating a coverall factory for the small stuff is obviously a no-no as they relate to different things and you lose encapsulation/clarity of purpose
- Creating a specific factory class for each of these seems like overkill, and also injecting it into every variety of a type of class seems like overkill too (i.e. 14 out of the 15 mentioned above don't need it)
- Including the service container goes some way to defeating the purpose of the exercise it seems
- Having a global 'make' function (like App:make() in Laravel 4 even though it's not actually a normal static call) moves us back towards globals and away from dependency injection
- Having a static constructor (e.g. Request::createFromGlobals in Symfony) prevents me from actually injecting things I need

So far I've injected the class needed by the 1 out of 15 and lived with it in one case, in another it didn't need actually any dependencies, so I just went with instantiating it directly even though my gut told me not to (guess what, my gut was right, one day later it could now probably do with a dependency or at least a construction service).

Most advice you read simply deals with big picture/idealised examples, but it feels like there might just be a nitty-gritty bit that you just have to fudge at the edge of your project. There's been some talk of passing an instance in then settings properties after the fact, but that doesn't feel right at all, especially if you want more than one copy - you'd end up having to clear state and things like that when really you just want a new one.

So how do I go about improving this one? Problem with the classes themselves? Problem with the structure as a whole?

Thanks.

Comment: How long does the class live, the 1 out or the 15?

Comment: A while, the 'factory' in that particular case is really a registry I guess? in that the instances of the classes it creates persist on it and are re-used (they are effectively state-less except for the construction requirements). It's somewhere where a bunch of business logic lives, part of a layer that was previously missing that now sits between the controllers and the datasource. This particular one handles a certain portion of the rules (remembering users) and encrypts certain data, and it's the only one that needs any encryption at all.

Comment: have you heard of [Auryn](https://github.com/rdlowrey/Auryn)? I've had a similar refactoring to do over a similarly-sized codebase and it really saved my life.

Comment: I've not heard of it no, thanks. Had a look and it doesn't really address my issue, just re-iterates the common wisdom about not passing the injector in without actually explaining how you avoid the situation I describe. It would perhaps make it easier though to have one class of a set use different construction parameters from the others, but this is something I could technically achieve already e.g. with a switch in the factory (clunky though).